# Mysql substract value of previous row to current row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table :

```
2017-10-29  10.812999999999999
2017-10-30  1.883
2017-10-31  15.746
2017-11-01  29.156
2017-11-02  42.552
```

I want to do the difference of the next day to the day before.

Example of output desired :

```
2017-10-29 (1.88-10.81)=-8,93
2017-10-30 13,863
```

etc...

Comment: could you please provide a sample table structure and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: you can use lead/lag function

Comment: "you can use lead/lag function" -> only in MySQL 8,0+ @saravanatn

Comment: Yes right but the person asking for help should mention what was the version using right???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select t.*, (t.val - tnext.val) as diff
from t left join
     t tnext
     on t.date = tnext.date - interval 1 day;
```

Comment: dont you need coalesce?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, depends on the wanted result for the row with the start date.

Comment: That is exactly what I asked for, perfect, thank you.